# Arrow animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make an animation of this picture[1] to this picture[2] in jquery?. I would like to get "a growing arrow effect". I must admit that after some searching i found nothing and simple

`$('#img').animate({width: '109px',height: '109px'});`

is not enough effect for me. Maybe you guys have some clues or tips to achieve that kind of effect.

[1] http://img543.imageshack.us/i/arrowmb.png/

[2] http://img687.imageshack.us/i/pngqa.png/

Comment: hmm You want it to grow on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: 
Try the code now, it shows the arrow in a green box contained on a red box and a click in the red box will grow and shrink the arrow compensating movement. Of course the boxes are for display purposes only you can remove the borders from the css.

The arrow was not moving anyway, the effect was because the image you provided has a blank space around the arrow which of course it also grow. You can clip the image to avoid having to compensate movement but anyway, the example illustrates that other properties can be also animated.

You just need to play a bit with the parameters to get the effect you are after.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.arrow_container').click(function() {
        $('img.arrow').animate({
          width: '+=70', height: '+=70', left: '-=15', top: '-=10'
        });
        $('img.arrow').animate({
          width: '-=70', height: '-=70', left: '+=15', top: '+=10'
        });
    });
});

</script>

<style>
.arrow_container {
    margin-left:30px; 
    margin-top:30px;
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.arrow {
    position:absolute;
    width:30;
    height:30;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="arrow_container">
        <img class="arrow"
        src="http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/9180/pngqa.png">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course you can do that, but this kind of emulation cause that left top arrow edge is moving. I wanted something like drawing arrow from left top corner to the right bottom corner in static box. I'm starting realize that this can't be done by javascript, but thanks for response.

Comment: This can be done, you can also change left, right params in the animation above, just fix the container and grow/move the arrow inside.